# Return Command for Callback Functions

Tags: javascript, callback

```
function twoSum(numbers, target) {
  var result = [];

  numbers.forEach(function(value, index) {
    return numbers.forEach(function(value2, index2) {
      if (value + value2 === target) {
        result.push(index, index2);
        return result;
      }
    }) 
  })
  return result;
}

twoSum([1, 2, 3], 4);
//Output - [ 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0 ]
```

Hi - I'm working on a particular codewars problem and I seem to be misunderstanding the usage of `return` for callback functions. In this particular problem I just want to find the first two sums of numbers that equal the target and push those index values into result. I don't want to keep iterating through my function after that - meaning I only want the first pair that's found. My current output gives me all the index values for the target sum. Not just the first 2. It seems I am not using my return commands correctly. My current line of thought is that `return result` returns a value to my nested callback of parameters `(value2, index2)`. That result is then returned to my outside function of `(value,index)`. Why does my loop not cease after that `return`?

Comment: `forEach()` doesn't return anything, and doesn't do anything with the return values of the callback functions.

Comment: There's no way to stop `forEach()` in the middle. If you want to stop after finding the first pair, use a `for` loop and then use `break` to stop.

Comment: Thank you. I thought I would be able to utilize the forEach() the same way I would if I used a `for loop`.

Comment: If you use jQuery you can use `$.each()`. It stops if the callback function returns `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't end because `.forEach` cannot be terminated early. `forEach` is not paying any attention to the values you return. If you want to terminate early you'll need to use a different approach.

If you want to stick with array methods, there are `.some` and `.every`. The former continues until a run of your function returns true, and the latter continues until a run of your function returns false. These are meant for doing compound OR's and compound AND's with every element of the array, but they can kinda be used for your case too.

```
numbers.some(function(value, index) {
  return numbers.some(function(value2, index2) {
    if (value + value2 === target) {
      result.push(index, index2);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }) 
})
```

Or you could use a standard for loop, with the `break` keyword when you want to stop the loop.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize you couldn't terminate `.forEach` early but it does make sense now that it does not pay any attention to the return values within itself

Answer (score 0):

Beside the not working `return` statement for a outer function, you need to take a different approach which uses only a single loop and an object for storing the index of the found value.

```js
function twoSum(numbers, target) {
    var indices = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        const number = numbers[i];
        if (number in indices) return [indices[number], i];
        indices[target - number] = i;
    }
}

console.log(twoSum([1, 2, 3], 4));
```